# Ссылки на загрузку файлов в Wordpress - 404 File not found

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, download

В процессе создания сайта на Wordpress (v 4.4.1) возникла проблема: при создании ссылок на файлы (pdf) выдает ошибку 404. Файлы лежат в папке под корнем сайта.

На локальном сервере (WebMatrix) все работает. На внешней песочнице - 404.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Довольно туманно описана проблема.
`при создании ссылок на файлы (pdf) выдает ошибку 404`
Что создаёт эти ссылки? Доступны ли файлы по прямым ссылкам? 404 выдаёт WP или сервер? Приведите примеры ссылок на файлы. Возможно в именах присутствуют символы, которые не нравятся серверу.

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро, для теста файл назван 1.pdf. По прямым ссылкам доступны с локального сервера, Пример ссылки: /Media/1.pdf.

Comment: @МаксЖуков, на внешнем сервере файлы по прямым ссылкам доступны? Сайт развернут в корневой директории или в подкаталоге? Регистр символов в именах файлов и директорий совпадает с тем, что используется в ссылке?

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро, на внешнем сервере файлы недоступны. Именно в этом и проблема.

Comment: @МаксЖуков, ответьте, пожалуйста, на остальные вопросы, заданные в предыдущем сообщении.

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро, сайт развернут в корневой директории, регистр совпадает.

Comment: @МаксЖуков, проверьте файл .htaccess или попробуйте его удалить, предварительно сделав бэкап.